# Trying to save & load user-inputted table rows

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to, once the user has added a new row to a table, save it to some kind of JSON array & whenever the tab that the table is in is loaded, to load that information out of the array & display it on the table.
(It's not usually relevant but I'm using electron.js)

I am relatively new to coding so I am still acquiring knowledge on this & I am quite sure I have a very messed up code system right now.

I first tried a simple `stringify` and `parse` function which didn't work as, of course, this is more complex than just that. Next, I wrote what is probably an extremely wrong method of writing an object array to save to the JSON & then parse it & now I've made what is quite a mess of code where after the JSON array is parsed a method that (is supposed to) readd the table row.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a very long time so help would be appreciated.

here is the javascript code:

```js
const addTableRow = () => {

  const name = document.querySelector("#name");
  const pnum = document.querySelector("#pnum");
  const age = document.querySelector("#age");

  let table = document.querySelector("#clientTable");

  let row = table.insertRow(-1);

  let c1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let c2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let c3 = row.insertCell(2);

  c1.innerHTML = name.value;
  c2.innerHTML = pnum.value;
  c3.innerHTML = age.value;

  const clientTable = {
    clientTable: [
      {
        name: c1.innerHTML,
        pnum: c2.innerHTML,
        age: c3.innerHTML
      }
    ]
  }

  const tableRowIn = JSON.stringify('clientTable');
  
  displayTableData();

  table.appendChild(row);
}

const createNewRow = (clientTable) => {
  return `<tr>
  <td>${clientTable.name}</td>
  <td>${clientTable.pnum}</td>
  <td>${clientTable.age}</td>
  </tr>`
}

const deleteTableRow = () => {
  document.querySelector('#clientTable').deleteRow(1);
}

const displayTableData = () => {
  JSON.parse('tableRowIn').then(createNewRow())
}
```

Here is also the HTML in case it's relevant:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Ezek's jsapp</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="tabs-container">
      <div class="tabs">
         <div class="tab active">Clients</div>
         <div class="tab">Files</div>
         <div class="tab">Settings</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
         <div class="content active">
            <h3>Clients</h3>
            <p>This is the clients tab</p>
            <form id="clForm">
               <label for="name">Name</label><br>
               <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
               <label for="pnum">Phone Number</label><br>
               <input type="text" id="pnum" name="pnum"><br>
               <label for="age">Age</label><br>
               <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br>
               <button onclick="addTableRow();">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <section class="wrapper-main">
               <table id="clientTable">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>PhoneNumber</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>ClientName</td>
                        <td>PhoneNumber</td>
                        <td>ClientAge</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>ClientName</td>
                        <td>PhoneNumber</td>
                        <td>ClientAge</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <button onclick="deleteTableRow();">Delete row</button>
               </table>
            </section>
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <h3>Files</h3>
            <p>This is the files tab, upload files here!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <h3>Settings</h3>
            <p>This is the settings tab</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      </divnp>
      <script src="renderer.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to store table data and retrieve the data when needed from a server, file system or other storage units. If you are using electron.js, I suppose this is a desktop app, if so you can store the data and retrieve it from local machine; otherwise server is your best option.

Comment: Have you looked into browser local storage?